# Dual monitors: one for gaming and one for browsing

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

There are some full screen games that when running, will prevent me from moving the mouse cursor to the other screen.  Is there a program that will allow me to do this?

My operating system is Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost all full-screen games consider themselves modal and will not let the mouse leave them while they are active though other applications are able to update their display on the other screen(s). I doubt there will be a way around this for the mouse - in FPS and TPS games for instance moving the mouse means "turn" not "move the pointer left/right" so there is no edge that you can move the mouse passed to tell it to go to the next monitor.

You don't have to quit quit your game to switch tasks though. I've not come across a game yet that blocks both the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and the "windows" key, so you can use one or both of those to switch control to your other applications and switch back to the game later. Though when you do this, the game will minimise itself and pause rather than just keep running without your control.

(caveat: I'm still on XP on the machine I use for gaming - though I doubt things are any different in this regard on Vista or 7)

Answer (score 5):

If your game has the ability to switch into a Windowed mode, then it would be possible.

I guess the only other method would be to load the game up in a virtual machine and have that VM's window set to a certain size. This is probably not going to be the best performance option.

Comment: By the way, sometimes even if the game is in windowed mode it wouldn't work. Sometimes games have their own cursor and they'll lock the OS cursor (usually) at the center of the game's window.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience this is a limitation that is imposed by a lot of full screen games and there isn't anyway around it. The fact is that most users (darn close to all) do not have multiple monitors, and probably aren't that much interested in surfing the web at the same time as playing a game; so it probably isn't real high on the priority list for someone to build this ability in. If I'm wrong, please post your answer how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I almost always play games in windowed mode (when possible) especially mmo type games where web access is *needed* the check on things. This seems to me to be the only way to make it work nicely (or the same way) with most games.